# Insert file into Google Drive - MIME type is incorrect

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to insert file into my Google Drive.

I use this method that I found here: [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert)

Here the signature:

```
/**
   * Insert new file.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
   * @param description Description of the file to insert.
   * @param parentId Optional parent folder's ID.
   * @param mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
   * @param filename Filename of the file to insert.
   * @return Inserted file metadata if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
   */
   private static File insertFile(Drive service, String title, String description,
  String parentId, String mimeType, String filename);
```

This is what I done into the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// Build a new authorized API client service.
Drive service = getDriveService();

java.io.File fi = new java.io.File("/home/davide/Scrivania/test.txt");
if (!fi.exists()) {
    fi.createNewFile();
}

insertFile(service, "test.txt", "JSON string of HashMap",
"/", "txt", "/home/davide/Scrivania/test.txt");
```

I don't know if I set the correct *parentId*, the documentation tells that it is optional.

But the error found is:

```
An error occured: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Media type 'txt' is not supported. Valid media types: [*/*]",
    "reason" : "badContent"
  } ],
  "message" : "Media type 'txt' is not supported. Valid media types: [*/*]"
}
```

**UPDATE**

With text/plain MIME type, the error is:

```
An error occured: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "file",
    "locationType" : "other",
    "message" : "File not found: /",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: /"
}
```

Comment: `txt` is not a valid [media type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) (MIME type). You probably want to use `text/plain` for the `mimeType` parameter instead.

Comment: @PhilRoss, I tried it. Not work again, please see the update above.

Comment: Please tidy up your question and post the solution as an answer. Otherwise it will probably get downvoted by the Spanish Inquisition.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

The parentId was incorrect.

I done `insertFile(service, "file.txt", "description", "", "text/plain", "/home/davide/Scrivania/test.txt");` and works.